# How to instantiate an instance of a subclass in a member variable in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subclass, private-members

I have a huge C++ code base I'm working with.

I want to introduce a new subclass, and use it in a variety of different contexts, however my Java trained mind is having trouble with this in C++.

I wish to minimize code changes.  So, my main class of interest (`BAR` below) has a member variable of class `FOO`.  I wish to make a subclass of `FOO` called `FOOSUBCLASS`.  In java this is trivial.  Objects are stored by reference by default.  This code does not do that (as seen below) can I massage this code, without changing interfaces (and without introducing references) and still make my application work?

```
class FOO {
};

class FOOSUBCLASS : FOO {
public:
    FOOSUBCLASS(const int id) {_id = id;}
private:
    int _id;
};

class BAR {
public:
    BAR(const FOO foo) { _foo = foo;}
private:
    FOO _foo;
};
```

Below, is my main:

```
FOOSUBCLASS fsc(1);
BAR b(fsc);
```

But this doesn't compile in VS2005.  It says:

'type cast' : conversion from 'FOOSUBCLASS *' to 'const FOO &' exists, but is inaccessible

Get same compiler error if I add the obvious other constructor to `BAR`

```
BAR(const FOOSUBCLASS foo) { _foo = foo;}
```

My understanding of C++ is that it will copy the data from `FOOSUBCLASS` into an object of class `FOO`.  (using the assignment operator, or a class overridden version of it) But in my case, I have additional member variables in `FOOSUBCLASS` (and some overridden member functions) so I just don't want it to do that.  I want my member variable `_foo` to truly be of type `FOOSUBCLASS` in some contexts, and `FOO` in others.  Is this even possible?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: `and without introducing references` Why?

Comment: @JesseGood because I want to avoid making huge changes in the code base.  This is a million line code base, and introducing references will change the lifecycle management of the application.  But, based upon answers below, it looks like I'm completely stuck with having to do that....

Comment: The only other option is to add another member `FOOSUBCLASS myfoosub;` and a `BAR(const FOOSUBCLASS)` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it the way you've written it now, sorry.  This is called "slicing", and more info about it can be found here: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

If you want your `_foo` member to be polymorphic, you'd need to use a pointer or a reference.  Be aware of lifetime management when you do things like this of course.

Answer (score 2):

Make the base class public

```
class FOOSUBCLASS : public FOO {
public:
    FOOSUBCLASS(const int id) {_id = id;}
private:
    int _id;
};
```

Also, beware of slicing in the `BAR` constructor

Assign to pointer/reference to avoid that:

```
class FOO
{
};

class FOOSUBCLASS : public FOO
{
public:
    FOOSUBCLASS(const int id) : _id(id) {}
private:
    int _id;
};

class BAR
{
public:
    BAR(const FOO& foo) : _foo(foo)
    {
    }
private:
    FOO& _foo;
};
```

Note: I used initializer-list syntax instead of assignments in the constructor body.

Comment: Well spotted regarding the public FOO .. subtle!

Comment: The public FOO gets it to compile, but doesn't deal with the slicing problem, which I now realize is the "real" issue.

Comment: @Huh. my code sample deals with that? I think I posted this "12 mins ago" :)

Comment: @sehe Agredd, but your solution changed the lifecycle model for FOO, and I can't do that in my code.  :(

Answer (score 1):

First in C++ classes by default use `private` to inherit from their base classes, this means that `FOOSUBCLASS` is a `FOO` but conversion is internal and is not accessible to you. So first convert `class FOOSUBCLASS : FOO` to `class FOOSUBCLASS : public FOO` and second is in Java every this is reference so you can say

```
FOOSUBCLASS fs;
FOO f = fs;
```

but in C++ we have references and non-references and using `FOO f` create a non-reference that is actually an object so `FOO f = fs` only copy `FOO` part of `fs` into `f` and does not cause a `FOO` reference to a `FOOSUBCLASS` to achieve this you should use pointer or reference or smart pointers. For example you can say:

```
FOOSUBCLASS* fs = new FOOSUBCLASS;
FOO* f = fs;   // Use pointer is OK
FOO& rf = fs;  // A reference of fs as a FOO
std::auto_ptr<FOO> spf( fs );  // OK, but for this destructor must be virtual
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to user sehe, consider passing a reference rather than passing by value to constructor of BAR.

`class BAR {
    public:
        BAR(const FOO& foo) { _foo = foo;}
    private:
        const FOO& _foo;
    };`